# Why is this function allowing me to use a lambda expression

Tags: java, generics, lambda

Why is this function that takes an interface as a parameter allowing me to write a lambda expression?

Take this function:

```
public ConditionBuilder<T> and(Condition<T> condition1) {
        conditional.getConditions().add(condition1);
        return this;
    }
```

This is what condition looks like:

```
public interface Condition<T> {
    boolean evaluate(T t);


    default boolean evaluateClause(T t, Condition<T> left, Condition<T> right, Operator operator) {
        switch (operator) {
            case AND:
                return left.evaluate(t) && right.evaluate(t);
            case OR:
                return left.evaluate(t) || right.evaluate(t);
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }


    default boolean evaluateStatement(T t, Collection<Condition<T>> conditions) {
        for (Condition condition : conditions) {
            if (!condition.evaluate(t)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why I am allowed to write a lambda expression for this interface. I thought I would have to pass something that implements that interface instead it is letting me write a lambda.

e.g.

```
return Conditional.<User>start(user -> isUserNameUnique(user.getUserName()))
            .and(user -> user.getFirstName() != null && user.getLastName() != null)
            .and(user -> !user.getFirstName().isEmpty() && !user.getLastName().isEmpty())
            .or(user -> isEmailUnique(user.getEmail()))
            .build();
```

Comment: Under the covers, the lambda **is** implementing that interface.

Comment: How does it know that the lambda requires a boolean?

Comment: @SamOrozco the interface has one abstract method, so the lambda body is used to implement that method.

Comment: @LouisWasserman So the lambda is just returning the evaluate function?

Comment: @SamOrozco read the lambda tutorial. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: Ok great. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a lambda expression all you need to do is create an interface with a `SAM` (Single Abstract method). After that, you can parameterize methods with the given interface meaning each time the method with the *behaviour parameterization* is called you will pass in a function that satisfies the *function descriptor* of the `SAM` within the interface along with the logic that function will perform. This in effect is the *implementation* of the `SAM`.

It's also a good habit to get into using the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation. this is used to indicate that an interface type declaration is intended to be a functional interface. the advantage with this is that the compiler checks that the interface only has a `SAM`.

Comment: and also add `@FunctionalInterface` annotation.

Comment: @dehasi i'll include that as a recommendation.

Comment: @dehasi Does `@FunctionalInterface` change the behavior at all?

Comment: No, it does not.